# Why I can't register callback to "normal-module-loader"

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my Webpack configuration, I am using UglifyJsPlugin, which registers a callback to "normal-module-loader", where it sets `context.minimize = true`. I wanted to set it to `false`, so I wrote another plugin to my config:

```
    plugins: [
        ...
        {
            apply: compiler => {
                console.log('apply was called');
                compiler.plugin('normal-module-loader', (context) => {
                    console.log('callback was invoked');
                    context.minimize = false;
                });
            }
        }
```

But the callback never gets invoked and I don't know why. When I register callback to some other event (eg. "done"), it gets invoked, only this "normal-module-loader" doesn't.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to access [`Compilation`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html#the-compilation-instance) instance first.

```
plugins: [
    ...
    {
        apply: compiler => {
            console.log('apply was called');
            compiler.plugin('compilation', compilation => {
                compilation.plugin('normal-module-loader', (context) => {
                    console.log('callback was invoked');
                    context.minimize = false;
                });
            });
        }
    }
```